# Is the try and catch considered one statement after an if?

Tags: java, if-statement

```
if (instance != null)
  try (InputStream stream = new FileInputStream(file)) {
    instance = getInstance(stream);
    instance.sourceFile = file;
    instances.put(instance.sourceFile.getPath(), instance);
    return instance;
  } catch (Exception e) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Cannot locate '" + file + "'. " + e, e);
  }
return instance;
```

Came across this in the codebase and wondering if the `if` applies to the entire try/catch or if it is being ignored. If the `if` is being applied to the entire try/catch I want to wrap it with curly braces but I don't want to break anything and I can't test it.

Comment: what *else* is the `if` supposed to apply to?

Comment: Why can't you test it? How about creating a similar example in another file with several statements in a try catch block just like this and see what happens there?

Comment: would be strange to have `try` separated from `catch`, or `catch` is only executed if `try` fails, so it must come together with a `try`. So yes, it is considered one statement (and all its content). And it sure would be better (for us humans to read) if you have the curly braces added

Comment: I can only imagine if the `try` fails, it will go into the `catch`. But why oh why would the person that wrote this not use braces. I’m a firm believer they should be used with every `if`, `for` etc for the simple reason of clarity if nothing else.

Comment: @JerryM branching statements don't require braces, from what I remember of the JLS it states they terminate at the next semicolon, but I'd venture a guess here that it applies to the entire code block / following statement. On a personal level, I don't advocate a lack of curly braces because of ambiguity and the potential to introduce bugs

Comment: It flows the same way with your intuition. The try statement does not affect the if-block because it is IN the if-block.

Comment: Note: you do not really need the first `return`, despite not wrong, just a case of preference

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger Yeah thanks for the tip. The IDE also tells me that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`try` `catch` is one statement, you can wrap the whole block into curly braces of the if-statement. This has the same semantic as your current code.

```
if (instance != null) {
  try (InputStream stream = new FileInputStream(file)) {
    instance = getInstance(stream);
    instance.sourceFile = file;
    instances.put(instance.sourceFile.getPath(), instance);
    return instance;
  } catch (Exception e) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Cannot locate '" + file + "'. " + e, e);
  }
}
```

A `catch` without a `try` is not allowed by the compiler, so you could also come to the same conclustion with trial and error where you set the closing brace.